# Create lines within polygons at given points

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

Given a spatial polygon

```
library(sf)

df <- data.frame(
  lon = c(119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.5, 119.5),
  lat = c(-5.192, -5.192, -5.167, -5.167, -5.191)
)

polygon <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")
```

with some points inside it

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  lon = c(119.45, 119.49, 119.47),
  lat = c(-5.172, -5.190, -5.183)
)

points <- df2 %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOINT")
```

how can I draw a straight, horizontal line through each point, from one end of the polygon to the other? That is, draw three straight lines within the polygon, each line crossing through one of the points. I have found several examples of drawing lines that connect points, or use points as start and end locations, but in my case the points simply mark the desired y-values of the horizontal lines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would have a look at the `geosphere` package: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/geosphere/index.html

Answer (score 2):

This approach just loops over the points and creates a new `LINESTRING` object with the x coordinates of the `POLYGON` and the y coordinates of the `POINT`:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  lon = c(119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.5, 119.5),
  lat = c(-5.192,-5.192,-5.167,-5.167,-5.191)
)

polygon <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

plot(polygon)

df2 <- data.frame(lon = c(119.45, 119.49, 119.47),
                  lat = c(-5.172,-5.190,-5.183))

points <- df2 %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOINT")

plot(points, add = TRUE, col = "red")


# Solution via a loop

xminmax <- c(min(df$lon), max(df$lon))

# Iterate and create lines
for (i in 1:3) {
  l <- st_linestring(matrix(
    c(xminmax[1],
      df2[i, "lat"],
      xminmax[2],
      df2[i, "lat"]),
    nrow = 2,
    byrow = TRUE
  ))
  # Create final object line
  if (i == 1) {
    line <- l
  } else {
    line <- c(line, l)
  }
}

# Result is line MULTILINESTRING object


plot(line, col = "green", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It seems like this answer should have the checkmark, no? Also, @dieghernan, how would you modify this to create lines that go in just one direction from the point, such as "due south?" My assumption would be to simply adjust the vals provided in the `matrix(...)` call?